# SQL Server Check DB IO requests taking longer than 15 seconds warning

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I am experiencing some problems with performing CHECKDB on my SQL Server. I am running SQL Server 2008 SP4 and SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU4. The SQL Server 2008 instance uses SAN storage, the SQL Server 2014 instance uses just local storage.

During CHECKDB is running I get messages in the error log like the following:

> SQL Server has encountered 61 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file ...

I am aware that my disks (local and SAN) are not optimal regarding throughput but unfortunately that's the setup I have to stick with in the nearer future. Furthermore the throughput is sufficient for my daily workload but the time CHECKDB is running things tend to get out of control and the disks are overwhelmed by the traffic generated.

CHECKDB is invoked by Ola Hallengren's Backup solution using commands like

> DBCC CHECKDB ([mydb]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY

The IO warnings in the error log are mainly for tempdb and for a few user database files.

Tempdb is configured according to the setup checklist by Brent Ozar: 8 datafiles, each pregrown to the sames size, autogrowth disabled.  The transaction log file resides on a different volume. I do not use any traceflags like 1117 and 1118 so far.

Interestingly I get the IO warnings on the SQL 2014 instance just after my biggest database have grown from 100GB to 200GB in a few days (resulting from data being migrated into the database...the usual growth rate is much lower).

The IO warnings on the SQL 2014 go along with timeouts in Nagios monitoring.
Here's a screenshot of the disk throughput from Nagios: The time CHECKDB runs the overall throughput (read and write) is identical with the max values over time:
[image: disk throughput]

Here's a statistic of disk throughput on checkdb with physical_only:
[image: disk throughput physical only]

Interestingly the IO warnings have gone now. Additionally there were no further timeouts on Nagios checks.

Is there anything I could do to get rid of the warnings and the IO overkill situation like

- telling CHECKDB to run slower and use less resources
- optimize the structure of my biggest database (VLF count? Index maintenance is running daily)
- moving tempdb to the SAN

The 2014 instance just got one local RAID drive consisting of two sata disks (due to blade server) which is partitioned for windows and has separate partitions for data, log and tempdb.
I am aware that this is against best practice configuration using different disks for tempdb, windows, data and log. But unfortunately there is currently no way to implement such a solution. I could switch using the SAN but unfortunately this is even slower most of the time (poorly configured...outdated technology...etc).

It's perfectly acceptable for you to think "man get a better IO subsystem and shut up" but as I wrote that's not possible short term. Therefore it would help tremeandously to be able to solve the problem in another way. As I said for my regular workload the current IO subsystem (however old fashioned it might seem) is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: you didn't mention RAM at all. I guess that's not an option for you

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the idea. I am open for any idea and just because it might not be possible for me to pursue that please don't hold back with it. Talking about RAM in particular: The Server has 192 GB of it. On the SQL 2014 instance this is barely used so far. Instead sp_blitz warns me of having to much free RAM.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure the server is configured to use the RAM? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx

Comment: Yes, most of it: Max server memory is 119.563 MB for the SQL instance. The box is also running Analysis Services therefore the memory is at that size.

Comment: sp_blitz says: "100GB of free memory inside SQL Server's buffer pool, which is 116GB. You would think lots of free memory would be good, but check out http://BrentOzar.com/go/freememory for more information."

Comment: It seems strange to me that you have SQL Server and SSAS but the RAM is hardly used but I really can't shed any light on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137733/discussion-between-martin-guth-and-nick-mcdermaid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use DBCC CHECKDB with physical_only option if you are checking consistency very day and weekly (on weekend - off peak time) execute normal DBCC CHECKDB, backup should include "checksum" option too.

Comment: Hi Bilal, thanks for the advice. I'll give physical_only a try. However I am not sure if it will have an effect on the SQL 2014 instance as this is a data warehouse and the nightly workload between weekdays and weekends does not differ much. I have got CHECKSUMs in my backups already.

Comment: In this case you can do normal checkdb once in a month, or in two months even

Comment: Wouldn't reducing MAXDOP on the CHECKDB command help as well reducing the IO because with less CPUs being used potentially SQL server is not fast enough processing what it already got from disk therefore reducing the stress on the disk itself? Does that make any sense :-) ?

Comment: Maxdop on checkdb is available from sql2014 sp2 onward if I am not wrong, but It will considerably increase duration of checkdb, so there are more chances of getting congested with other db operations. Disk is always slower than couples so I would still suggest what I said above :)

Comment: * Disk is slower than CPU.

Comment: I have tried now running CHECKDB with PHYSICAL_ONLY. Runtime is 46 mins compared to 68 mins for regular checkdb (22 mins faster). Interestingly IO throughput (especially for write activity) has dropped. Now the Nagios checks don't get timeouts anymore.

Comment: Indeed this has ease the IO load, do you think above answer should be marked ?

Comment: No further IO warnings now. However I am a little worried about PHYSICAL_ONLY...i didn't manage to obtain proper information what checks this actually omits and what could possibly go wrong. [Kendra Little](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/dbcc-checkdb-faq/) advocates againt using that option because it turns "off valid feature(s) in CheckDB that could really save your bacon". Thus I am not very comfortable using it. For that server I actually don't care if CHECKDB runs for 1 hour or 2 hours....I just want to make sure it does not throw IO errors and overwhelm my IO subsystem

Comment: Physical_only will skip logical checks, inter-page checks and will report physical errors like not able to access specific page(s) at all. That's why I recommend to use checkdb weekly or monthly to have full consistency check in place. checksum plays an important role in backup and "page_verify" as well.

Comment: Hi Bilal, thanks for clarifying that. Ideally I would like to get rid of the IO overload completely while having full CHECKDB tests. Running full CHECKDB weekly or monthly just eases a bit on the problem but doesn't solve it. On the downside I probably would not get notfication about corruption soon enough to do something against it. I have just tested running CHECKDB with MAXDOP 1 but that doesn't help either. In the long run I will be doing regular backup recovery testing and could outsource CHECKDB to another server. Until then I'll probably live with the IO warnings :-(.

Comment: You have another option of checktable.